# Change a buttons text using actionPerformed() and actionListener

Tags: java, swing, methods

I am attempting to change the text of the a button, based off the first button being clicked. I don't have an issue with the `actionPerformed()` method changing the value of the button if I hard code the string value I want passed, but when I attempt to change the buttons text based off of a method with an array of string values, it does not recognize it. I feel its an easy fix, but I can't seem to find it.

Here are the necessary classes:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class myJPanel6 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    myJButton b1, b2;

    public myJPanel6() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        //=====================================
        student st1 = new student("Michael", "Robinson", 20);
        //=====================================
        b1 = new myJButton(st1.getName());
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        add(b1);
        //=====================================
        b2 = new myJButton(st1.WhatIsUp());
        add(b2);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object obj = event.getSource();
        if (obj == b1) {
            b2.setText(st1.whatIsUp());
        }
    }
}
```

```
class student {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;
    String status;

    public student(String a, String b, int c) {
        firstName = a;
        lastName = b;
        age = c;

        if (age <= 25) {
            status = "Traditional";
        } else {
            status = "Non-Traditional";
        }
    }

    String getName() {
        return ("NAME = " + firstName + "  " + lastName + ", Age = " + age + ", Status = " + status);
    }

    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    String WhatIsUp() {
        String b = "dunno";
        double r = Math.random();
        int myNumber = (int) (r * 3f);
        if (myNumber == 0) {
            b = "reading";
        }
        if (myNumber == 1) {
            b = "talking";
        }
        if (myNumber == 2) {
            b = "interacting";
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: Proper naming convention is to have class names capitalized.  Will make it easier for other people to read your code.

Answer (score 1):

`st1` is declared locally to the constructor, meaning it can't be accessed from the `actionPerformed` method.

You need to make `st1` an instance variable like you buttons

For example...

```
public class myJPanel6 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    myJButton b1, b2;
    private student st1;

public myJPanel6() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    //=====================================
    st1 = new student("Michael", "Robinson", 20);
```

**Updated**

Without further information, the `WhatIsUp` method is package-private, meaning it can only be accessed from within the package the class was declared, you'll need to make `public` if you want to access it else where

```
public String WhatIsUp() {...
```

Comment: Doing that still does not allow me access to the method in the student class that I am trying to reach. Is it even possible for me to access the method the way I am attempting to?

Comment: Now all the code is working, but I am getting a NullPointException error

Comment: Apart from the fact that your example code actually can't compile, I have no issues

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the method `WhatIsUp` in `student` `public` so you have the ability to call it.  Leaving out the access modifier in `Java` defaults to `protected` modifier.

eg:

```
public String WhatIsUp() {
    String b = "dunno";
```

---

Also as @MadProgrammer suggested - you need to make `st1` an `instance variable`.

---

Side Note: All of your methods except for `WhatIsUp` begin with a lowercase letter.  You should keep the formatting the same and change it to `whatIsUp`.  This also follows the Java conventions.